# How to properly combine aframe, threeJS, npm, and webpack?

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, three.js, aframe

I am trying to understand the expected way to set up an AFRAME project and use npm/webpack to install dependencies, including things like `three/addons`.

I am new to node (and especially webpack), but I have a package.json set up to run a simple server:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "test",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "aframe": "^1.3.0"
  }
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=16"
  }
}
```

In my `/public` directory, I have several html files + js files in various nested directories which use AFRAME (which I was previously loading from CDN).

What's the "right" way to give these scripts access to AFRAME without CDN?  What about `three`, `three/addons`, or any other ThreeJS/AFRAME npm package?

I gather that I need to use webpack?  Can I configure webpack to generate a single bundle.js file that includes all of my dependencies, and then `import` as desired from that?  I don't fully understand the relationship between webpack's bundling and ES6 imports, or how to configure webpack in this way.

Thank you!

EDIT: based on the comments below, here is my package.json now:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "test",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "aframe": "git://github.com/aframevr/aframe.git#54022b80c60b12dc755f4f4a71a779b410dd23d0",
    "aframe-htmlembed-component": "^1.0.0",
    "aframe-extras": "^6.1.1",
    "aframe-instanced-mesh": "^0.6.1",
    "networked-aframe": "^0.11.0",
    "@react-three/drei": "^9.46.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^5.75.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.0.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=16"
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js:

```
// From: https://github.com/Chabloz/a-frame-webpack-boilerplate
const path = require("path");

const config = {
  mode: "development",
  devtool: "inline-source-map",
  entry: "./src/main.js",
  output: {
    filename: "bundle.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "public/dist")
  },
  watch: false,
  resolve: {
    modules: [
      path.resolve("./src"),
      path.resolve("./node_modules")
    ]
  },
  externals: {
    three: "THREE"
  }
};

module.exports = (env, argv) => {
  return config;
};
```

and /src/main.js:

```
// AFRAME
require("aframe");

// Helpers
require("aframe-htmlembed-component");
require("aframe-extras");
require("aframe-instanced-mesh/src/instanced-mesh");
require("@react-three/drei");

// NAF
require("networked-aframe");
```

This sucessfully generates /public/dist/bundle.js when I run `webpack`, and I can include it like so:

```
    <script src="/dist/bundle.js"></script>
```

But when I try to import any of the modules in the bundle from another script (`import * as THREE from "three"`), I get `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "three". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".`.  If I change it to `import * as THREE from "/dist/bundle.js"`, I get `bundle.js:36779 Uncaught Error: A a-node type is already registered`

Comment: Webpack + A-Frame boilerplate https://github.com/Chabloz/a-frame-webpack-boilerplate

Comment: @DiegoMarcos thank you!  this seems very close to what I need.  but in that example. there's no node.js server (which I need for other things).  is there anything special I have to do to combine these approaches?  if I leave my `"start": "node server.js"` and add the     `"build": "webpack",` + `"dev": "webpack --mode=development --watch"` lines, it doesn't seem to be generating `dist/bundle.js`

Comment: I've tried a few things like:
`
    "start": "webpack",
    "dev-server": "node server.js",
    "dev-client": "webpack-dev-server --port 3000"
`
but it seems to blow through glitch's memory limit...

Comment: Did you try running it locally? What OS are you on?

Comment: @PiotrAdamMilewski it succeeds if I run it through the glitch terminal (as opposed to via the package.json), but still reaches 500 MB+ memory usage and the output bundle.js is 1.27 MB.  is that right?  main.js is just `require("aframe")`. glitch runs on Ubuntu 16.04.7

Comment: I'm also running into some new issues:
1. if I try to bundle aframe-instanced-mesh, webpack fails: "Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './instanced-mesh.js' in '/rbd/XXXX/node_modules/aframe-instanced-mesh'".  if I try to include it from CDN (after my bundle), I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: AFRAME is not defined at instanced-mesh.js:1:1`
2. my bundle also fails to find AFRAME: `Uncaught ReferenceError: AFRAME is not defined at 1191 (bundle.js:1:248705)`
3. `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "aframe". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".`

Comment: it seems you can't just require `aframe-instanced-mesh`, you need to provide a full path, like [here](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/agitated-hawking-b3dqd7)

Comment: @PiotrAdamMilewski aha! thank you, that resolved that issue! I'm still hitting an error in the bundle though: `Uncaught TypeError: l[e] is not a constructor at HTMLElement.value (bundle.js:2:2117762)` (which is `this.systems[e]=new l[e](this)`) and `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "aframe". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".` when I try to import * as AFRAME from "aframe" (and the same issue with THREE) in any of my other JS files

Comment: seems like I shouldn't mark bundle.js as a module...then it works until I try to import, and I still get `import * as THREE from "three"`.  if I change it to `import * as THREE from "/dist/bundle.js"`, I get `bundle.js:36779 Uncaught Error: A a-node type is already registered`

Comment: for future googlers: the above info was very helpful but I gave up on this approach and switched to using React/create-react-app which lets you use npm/import without having to do any bundling yourself and everything just works